# Google play leaderboard - unable to submit scores

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have implemented a google play services leaderboard in my app recently, but found out it does not submit scores.

I have an instance of GoogleApiClient from MainActivity which is declared static to be used in other activities. The code to visit leaderboard is in MainActivity.

```
public static GoogleApiClient apiClient = apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Games.API)
                .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to connect to google play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

The code to submit score is inside a method that is called from onActivityResult of a second activity (and once in onCreate for testing). Because it's in onActivity result, the googleApiClient is not instantly connected and results in failure if I update directly, so I did something like this:

```
MainActivity.apiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                PendingResult r = Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(MainActivity.apiClient,
                        getString(R.string.leaderboard_most_stars),
                        totalStars);
                ResultCallback callback = new ResultCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {}
                };
                r.setResultCallback(callback);
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

            }
        });
```

But it fails to submit score for some reason. Leaderboard loads, just shows no scores.

And wierd thing is, it works fine on an emulator on a test account.

Can anybody help in pointing out the mistake?

Comment: Have you tried to check the Result and see if there is any clue in it?

Comment: It does work on the emulator, I did check with Log and toasts, and it is as expected. Just isn't working on real devices for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, check and make sure that you've correctly provided the SHA-1 of your signing certificate. Note that release certificate fingerprint is different from debug certificate fingerprint.

From [Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth),

To get the release certificate fingerprint:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

To get the debug certificate fingerprint (for Windows):

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

In addition to that, I suggest that you also consider looking into [Quality Checklist for Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) especially on [sign-in](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#1_sign-in) and [leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#3_leaderboards).

Comment: Hmm, I've never done anything from terminal so far.. I tried but it said keystore exists at the location but is empty.

Also, I currently do not meet all sign-in requirements from checklist (don't have a manual sign-in.
so is that a cause?